# How to launch Glue Jobs from CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I modified this example from the AWS documentation to specify my Glue jobs, but nothing happens:

```
Resources:
  ScheduledJobTrigger:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Trigger
    Properties:
      Type: SCHEDULED
      Description: DESCRIPTION_SCHEDULED
      Schedule: cron(0 */2 * * ? *)
      Actions:
        - JobName: prod-job2
        - JobName: prod-job3
          Arguments:
            '--job-bookmark-option': job-bookmark-enable
      Name: prod-trigger1-scheduled
```

This script is in a YAML file that I uploaded to CloudFormation. I used all the default settings after the import. After the specified cron time, nothing happens.

What else is needed to launch Glue jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property `StartOnCreation` to `True`. It is not supported for `ON_DEMAND`triggers.

Comment: Thanks, you are a lifesaver!